# Saving copies in m2m django orm

Tags: python, django, django-models

Inside my code, I am trying to save copies of one object inside m2m, but only one instance is saved. How can I save several of them?

```
def add_to_basket(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        basket_id = request.session.get('BID')
        if not basket_id:
            basket_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
            request.session['BID'] = basket_id
        basket, created = Basket.objects.get_or_create(id=basket_id)
        if created:
            basket.save()
        ticket_id = request.POST.get('ticket_id')
        count = request.POST.get('count')
        ticket = Tickets.objects.get(id=int(ticket_id))
        if ticket.count - int(count) > 0:
            for i in range(int(count)):
                new_ticket = Tickets.objects.get(id=int(ticket_id))
                new_ticket.count = new_ticket.count - 1
                new_ticket.save()
                basket.tickets.add(new_ticket)
            basket.save()
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'ok'})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'not enough tickets'})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'not get method'})
```

```
class Basket(models.Model):
    id = models.TextField(verbose_name='ID Корзины', primary_key=True)
    tickets = models.ManyToManyField(Tickets, verbose_name='Билеты')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата создания')

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'tickets': [ticket.to_json() for ticket in self.tickets.all()],
            'date': self.date
        }

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Корзина'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Корзины'
```

I tried to add tickets, in this code I am already creating a separate instance

Comment: You don't create new `Ticket`s, you simply update the existing `Ticket`, and an m2m is by default unique, hence it will indeed only add the item once.

Comment: And how can this be done? I just haven't worked with m2m in django

Answer (score 0):

You are *not* creating copies, you simply want to refer to the *same* ticket, and in the loop, you each time decrease the `.count` with one, but ultimately, it is the same `Ticket` record (with the same primary key).

Likely you can work with `IndividualTicket` that can then thus be stored in the basket, but perhaps your `Ticket` model is a bit of a misnomer: since it contains `.count` it looks more like an `Event` or perhaps a `TicketDeck` or something similar:

```
class Basket(models.Model):
    id = models.TextField(verbose_name='ID Корзины', primary_key=True)
    tickets = models.ManyToManyField(
        Tickets, through='IndividualTicket', verbose_name='Билеты'
    )
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата создания')

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            'id': self.id,
            'tickets': [ticket.to_json() for ticket in self.tickets.all()],
            'date': self.date,
        }

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Корзина'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Корзины'


class IndividualTicket(models.Model):
    basket = models.ForeignKey(Basket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Tickets, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

then the view creates `IndividualTicket`s in bulk:

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST


@require_POST
def add_to_basket(request):
    basket_id = request.session.get('BID')
    if not basket_id:
        basket_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        request.session['BID'] = basket_id
    basket, created = Basket.objects.get_or_create(id=basket_id)
    ticket_id = request.POST.get('ticket_id')
    count = int(request.POST.get('count', 1))
    ticket = get_object_or_404(Tickets.objects, id=ticket_id))
    if ticket.count - count > 0:
        Tickets.objects.filter(id=ticket_id).update(count=F('count') - count)
        IndividualTicket.objects.bulk_create(
            [IndividualTicket(ticket=ticket, basket=basket) for _ in range(count)]
        )
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'ok'})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'not enough tickets'}, status_code=400)
```

That being said, it is not clear to me why you actually need to store individual tickets. In the `ManyToManyField` you could also store the ordered count. Furthermore *storing* and *updating* the `count` in `Ticket` introduces all sorts of race conditions.